# Apply @RolesAllowed annotations to existing users stored in database

Tags: java, authentication, servlets, jersey-2.0, servlet-filters

**TLDR**
There is a need in the Java Web Application I develop, to implement user distinction over the REST services. I know that there are some annotations (`@RolesAllowed`, `@PermitAll`, `@DenyAll`), that can describe which role can use the service. My question is, how can I match the roles from `@RolesAllowed` with user role enumaration, that user is a persisted object stored in a DB??

<sup>Many tutorials explain the `@RolesAllowed`, but I found none to match those roles, with already created ones</sup>

---

**Explanation**

How to validate a user, by checking his role (found by session ID) automatically? I know Jersey do this already, by registering `RolesAllowedDynamicFeature.class`. I already managed to check that this `RolesAllowedDynamicFeature.class` works, by putting the `@DenyAll` annotation into a method, and returned a 403 error.

First of all, let's start with what is a user. Users are DB Entities, using `Ebean` to persist them from and to Java objects. Here is a sample from a `User.class`:

```
/*
* A sample that describes the fields that I ask for and to understand the concept
*/
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User extends Model
{
   @Id
   @GeneratedValue
   @Column(name = "id")
   private long id;

   @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
   @Column(name = "role", nullable = false)
   private UserRole role;

   // contructors getters setters helper methods etc

   /**
    * Fetch a user from DB
    *
    * @param id the id to search for
    * @return a Person.class object or may return null
    */
   public static User getUserById(Long id)
   {
      return Ebean.find(User.class, id);
   }

   /* and here is the UserRole enum that define the roles every user can have */
   public static enum UserRole
   {
      Administrator, User, Manager;
   }
}
```

All above code, works fine, user are stored correctly and I can fetch them easily.

Every User, at login, is authenticated with a similar service and a ConnectedUser object is created with a unique session ID (using UUID) for each one.
After each service call, there is an authentication running, that Authenticates if a user can use this service by searching, if there is a connected user entry for this session (which is stored as a cookie):

```
@Secured
@Provider
@Priority(Priorities.AUTHENTICATION)
public class AuthenticationFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter
{
   @Context
   private HttpServletRequest request;

   /**
    * Authenticates a user's access with every request that is made via a token.
    *
    * @param requestContext The request that is sent to the server.
    * @throws IOException
    */
   @Override
   public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) throws IOException
   {
      boolean isValidated;

      Cookie sessionCookie = null;
      Cookie[] cookies = request.getCookies();

      if (cookies.length != 0) {
         for (Cookie cookie : cookies) {
            if (cookie.getName().equals("CookieName")) {
               sessionCookie = cookie;
            }
         }
      }

      if (sessionCookie != null) {
         // UserValidationHandler checks if user is in connected_users table
         isValidated = UserValidationHandler.validateUser(sessionCookie.getValue(), request.getRemoteAddr());
      }
      else {
         MultivaluedMap pathParameters = requestContext.getUriInfo().getQueryParameters();

         // UserValidationHandler checks if user is in connected_users table
         isValidated = UserValidationHandler.validateUser((String)pathParameters.getFirst("token"), request.getRemoteAddr());
      }

      if (!isValidated) {
         LOGGER.warn("[Authorization filter] Unauthorized user.");
         URI indexURI = URI.create("http://login.jsp");
         requestContext.setRequestUri(indexURI);
      }
   }
}
```

---

**Notes:**

Note1: Most implementations suggest to apply the roles into web.xml file. This is not doable though I think, for my case.

Note2: Also, where is the right place to authorize a user to use a service? I found that I can create `ContainerRequestFilter` class, with `@Priority(Priorities.AUTHORIZATION)`. Which is better to do?

I'm kinda lost here. I read many of the Q/As or samples out there, but nothing explain it thorough.

Comment: Yes, you should implement ContainerRequestFilter and put your authorization code there. You should also create a class that implements SecurityContext as well as a class that implements Principal. I'll post some code when I find the time.

Comment: @dsp_user I'll look what you said (as i understand, the "yes" refers to the Note2). If you manage to post a code sample sometime, it will be much appreciated!! Thank you

Comment: Yes,  my comment about implementing ContainerRequestFilter refers to note #2. Like I said, I'll post some code because it may still not be obvious how it works together.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should separate the concerns and do the *authentication* in one filter and *authorization* in one filter. Generally how this is accomplished is by setting the `SecurityContext` from inside the authentication filter, and then retrieving it from inside the authorization filter.

The `SecurityContext` has a `isUserInRole` method that you override. This method should be called in the authorization filter. Generally you will have the roles as a member of the `SecurityContext`, and just iterate the roles

```
static class MySecurityContext implements SecurityContext {
    private final String[] userRoles;

    public MySecurityContext(String[] roles, String user) {
        this.userRoles = roles;
    }

    @Override
    public Principal getUser() {
        return new Principal() {
            @Override
            public String getName() {
                return name;
            }
        }
    }

    public boolean isUserInRole(String role) {
        for (String userRole: userRoles) {
            if (role.equals(userRole) {
                return true;
            }
        } 
        return false;
    }

    // more methods to override
}
```

In the authentication filter, you just call the `requestContext.setSecurityContext` method passing in the new `SecurityContext`.

In the authorization filter, you would get the `@RolesAllowed` annotation by using the `ResourceInfo`. For example

```
class AuthorizationFilter implement ContainerRequestContext {
    @Context
    private ResourceInfo info;

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext request) {
        SecurityContext sc = request.getSecurityContext();
        RolesAllowed anno = info.getResourceMethod().getAnnotation(RolesAllowed.class);
        String rolesAllowed = anno.value();
        for (role: rolesAllowed) {
            if (sc.isUserInRole(role)) {
                 return;
            }
        }
        request.abortWith(Response.status(403).build());
    }
}
```

Or something along those lines.

If you are using Jersey2 though, you don't need to implement the authorization yourself. This is already implemented in the [`RolesAllowedDynamicFeature`](https://github.com/jersey/jersey/blob/2.26/core-server/src/main/java/org/glassfish/jersey/server/filter/RolesAllowedDynamicFeature.java#L120). You just need to register the feature with your application. It works the same as I mentioned previously; A `SecurityContext` is expected to be filled prior to reaching the authorization filter, the the filter will check the roles and either authorize or reject.

Comment: This makes sense... I already managed to add the `RolesAllowedDynamicFeature` in my application. But, how is it possible for this class, to match the User's Roles (that as I said are stored as varchars in DB) with `@RolesAllowed` automatically? Also, as I understand from your concept, the request pass first from the `Authentication filter` and then from the `Authorization filter`. But what the --"A `SecurityContext` is expected to be filled prior to reaching the authorization filter"-- actually means? I must pass into the response/request this context when passing from one filter to the other?

Comment: The authorization filter that comes with the `RolesAllowedDynamicFeature` will try to get the `SecurityContext` from the `ContainerRequestContext` and then take the roles that you specify in the `@RolesAllowed` annotation, then check those against the `SecurityContext` by calling the `isUserInRole`  of the `SecurityContext`. I showed an example above. As you can see, I simply allow passing the rolls in through the `SecurityContext` constructor.

Comment: The authentication filter will be called _before_ the authorization filter, so in the authentication filter, you need to set the `SecurityContext` by simply calling `setSecurityContext` on the `ContainerRequestContext`. In the authentication filter, how is usually works, is that when you authenticate, you need to need to grad the user information from the DB, so at this time you should also grab the user roles. After you determine it is a valid user, this is when you populate the `SecurityContext` with those roles and set the security context on the request context.

Comment: Wow! That `.setSecurityContext()` is what I missed. Also I didn't heard of the detail that we usually fetch the object from the DB during Authentication. That really clarifies the process! Thank's for your time. I'll try to implement it and probably it will work. Otherwise, I'll bother you again for this later.

Answer (score 2):

My implementation is different from that of `peeskillet` but it has worked for me.

The code implementing security might look something like this

```
public class ServiceFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext req) throws IOException {

        //user name and password are obtained from the header
        String auth = req.getHeaderString(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION);

        if(auth == null) {
            throw new WebApplicationException(Status.UNAUTHORIZED);
        }

        //user name and password
        String[] credentials = auth.substring(1, auth.length()-1).split(":");

        String user = credentials[0];//user name
        String password = credentials[1];//password

        if(user == null || password == null)
             throw new WebApplicationException(Status.UNAUTHORIZED);

        ServiceSecurity ss = null;
        //user name and password are hardcoded here but you better put them in a DB or file
        if(user.equals("servUser") && password.equals("service"))
         ss = new ServiceSecurity(new ServiceUser("servUser"));
        else if(user.equals("servAdmin") && password.equals("admin"))
            ss = new ServiceSecurity(new ServiceUser("servAdmin"));
        else
             throw new WebApplicationException(Status.UNAUTHORIZED);

        req.setSecurityContext(ss);

    }
}
```

The security context

```
import java.security.Principal;

import javax.ws.rs.core.SecurityContext;

public class ServiceSecurity implements SecurityContext {

    private ServiceUser sUser;
    public ServiceSecurity(ServiceUser sUser){
        this.sUser = sUser;
    }

    @Override
    public String getAuthenticationScheme() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return SecurityContext.DIGEST_AUTH;
    }

    @Override
    public Principal getUserPrincipal() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return sUser;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isSecure() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isUserInRole(String role) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return sUser.getRole().equals(role) ? true : false;
    }

}
```

The security context implementation class is initialized with a class implementing Principal (ServiceUser), which is used to get the role for this particular user.

```
import java.security.Principal;

public class ServiceUser implements Principal {

    private String role;

    public ServiceUser(String role){
        this.role = role;
    }
    public ServiceUser(){

    }
    public String getRole(){
        return role;
    }
    public void setRole(String role){
        this.role = role;
    }
    public String getName(){
        return "some name";
    }
}
```

In this case, you'd add the following to your server method

```
@RolesAllowed("servUser")
```

The credentials (user name and password) should be supplied in the request header (as is evident from the filter method above)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! But as I see it, in the `ServiceFilter` you get the username and password from the header of the request. I need this filtering to happen in every service that is called for my application and it's not possible to request username and password every time from user nor add them in every ajax request manually. Any solution about this?

Comment: In that case, you will probably have to use some session tracking or some other way of providing state (as far as login is concerned). Normally, REST is stateless but you can still provide state information if you need to. So, authenticate the user only one and then set a session variable (e.g. myServLogin=true). Then for subsequent requests, check that this session variable is true. Of course, there are other ways to do this.

Comment: Oh I see your point. I authenticate each user at login time. Otherwise he will not be able to call any service at all. But my need is, for every request that come to the server, I need to check if the user that made the request, can use the current service. For example, admins and users are both authenticated at login. But admins, can call more services than a simple user. When a page opens (either for admin or user), it sends some ajax requests to the server. My restriction level is per service and I don't want users be able to call admin's services. Thank's for your time to answer though.

Comment: With a session  (sessions are per user, not per request) you can achieve all that.